Alternative to create non-object elements like gizoms
I want to create a dimension like in autocad. So there is the dimension object which is visible and two small points which only appear when I want to edit my dimension. How to create your little points? Does this only work with gizmos or is it also possible to create your little points with operators?
What should I know before getting into this?
